# Bindmodel to binded model? Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

[image]

I bind ProductsPhoto to children using bindModel method:

```
$this->Category->bindModel(array
            ('hasMany' => array(
                'ProductsPhoto' => array...
```

How can I bind ProductsPhoto to every product item?

Or maybe any other solution suggestion?

Comment: $this->ProductsPhoto->bindModel() ?

Answer (score 2):

in your controller ,write below code

```
$this->ProductsPhoto->bindModel('hasMany' => array('Product.productphoto_id' => 'ProductPhoto.id');
```

in your ProductPhoto model,

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Product' =>
                array(
                    'className' => 'ProductPhoto',
                    'foreignKey' => 'productphoto_id',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => '',
                    'counterCache' => ''
            ),  

);
```

Answer (score 1):

On the fly: `$this->ProductsPhoto->bindModel('hasMany' => 'Product');`

Via `ProductsPhoto` class property: `$hasMany = 'Product';`